# Extract a value in a json response with a variable

Tags: java, json, response, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to return the id of a declared variable from a json file: i want my java code to search for the previous variable in the json response and once it is found -> return the corresponding id.
I am using RestAssured in java.

Json file response example:

```
[
 {
  "class" : "test 1",
  "id"    : 5,
  "variable" : 87
  },
 {
  "class" : "test 2",
  "id"    : 7,
  "variable" : 76
  }
]
```

Now, i do something like that but i have no idea:

```
Response response = given()
                .config(config)
                .header("accept","application")
                .when()
                .get("requestID")
                .then()
                .extract().response();

String id = String.valueOf(response.
                body().
                jsonPath().
                get("id").toString().contains(variable));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just to parse your Json. This could be done very simply. You can parse your given Json to a `List<Map>` or you can create a simple class lets call it `MyClassInfo`and parse your Json to a `List<MyClassInfo>`. Your `MyClassInfo` would look like this:

```
public class MyClassInfo {
  @JsonProperty("class")
  private String myClass;
  private Integer id;
  private Integer variable;
  // Add setters and getters here
}
```

Now you can easily parse it using Json Jackson library:
ForMaps:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> myList;
ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//Add setters for ObjectMapper configuration here if you want a specific config
try {
  myList = objectMapper.readValue(myJsonString, List.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

And for `MyClassInfo` class

```
List<MyClassInfo> myList;
ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//Add setters for ObjectMapper configuration here if you want a specific config
try {
  myList = objectMapper.readValue(myJsonString, List.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

Now you can just go through your list and extract from each `map` or `MyClassInfo` the required id.

Just to simplify it a bit more you can do parsing with `JsonUtils` class from MgntUtils library written by me. Here is the code with `JsonUtils` class (just for `MyClassInfo` class:

```
    List<MyClassInfo> myList;
    try {
      myList = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(myJsonString, List.class);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    ...
    }
```

Note that in this case you won't have to instantiate and configure `ObjectMapper` instance as `readObjectFromJsonString` is a static method. Anyway if you are interested in using my library you can find maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and The library itself with source code and javadoc is on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Javadoc for `JsonUtils` class is [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution here, query by condition with GPath syntax.

```
int id = response.jsonPath().get("find {it.variable == 87}.id");
```

Comment: I tried but i have an error : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: 'it.transactionId == 2d' @ line 1, column 33.
                            find {it.transactionId == 2de2a08e-98ac-422b-86ca-c458ee11db35}.id
                                   ^

1 error

Comment: your `transactionId` is text, you need to put it it single quote. `find {it.transactionId == '2de2a08e-98ac-422b-86ca-c458ee11db35'}.id`

Answer (score 0):

We can use jsonpath to get a list of objects matching our criteria and return a list or map.

```
Response response = given()
                .config(config)
                .header("accept","application")
                .when()
                .get("requestID")
                .then()
                .extract().response();
```

Here I'm assuming the variable is `class='test 1'`. You can give any criteria to match against.

```
List<Integer> ids = response.jsonpath().get("*[?(@.class=='test 1')]..id");

System.out.println(ids.get(0));
```

Refer: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath